# How to intercept network traffic from VSCode using Proxyman?

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy, settings, proxyman

I'm using VSCode and running some automated tests that are sending API requests to https://restful-booker.herokuapp.com domain.

Now, I normally use Proxyman to inspect such requests from various apps (Postman, pycharm, brave browser etc) and it works without issues. Example of sending a request form Postman that's intercepted by Proxyman:[request from postman in proxyman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq2bl.png)
That proves the point that my setup on macOS is correct.

Running 'npm test' to run the test below (which definitely sends a request to that domain):
[api test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g28Xq.png)
Unfortunately, that request cannot be seen in Proxyman.

I strongly believe that the issue lies in VSCode because I cannot see any traffic from that app. Does it work for anybody? How did you make it work?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

[image: setup]

I had to manually run the postman setup in vscode terminal in order to intercept the traffic from the terminal I was running the tests in

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing 